# Issues connecting to a DB2 server using Python. Possible issue identifying the driver

Tags: python, db2, odbc

I had written code to connect to a DB2 server using Python that was working fine until my company had me upgrade the IBM DB2 Driver to 11.5.  Now, its no longer working and I'm getting the following error message:
**SQLCODE=-30082n: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30082N  Security processing failed with reason "15" ("PROCESSING FAILURE").  SQLSTATE=08001**

I verified that I have the right password.  Also, I confirmed that I still have access to the Database by going through the ODBC Manager in Windows and testing a connection that way. I've checked several pages here on Stackoverflow and other sites and nothing seems to work.  Most of the issues people are having on this site involve different error messages.

Here is the original code using the ibm_db module:

```
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi

con = ibm_db_dbi.Connection(ibm_db.connect("ABC1011","rsmith","Passw123"))
```

When that stopped working i tried connecting using pyodbc as a connection:

```
import pyodbc 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY2};Database=ABC1011;UID=rsmith; PWD=Passw123')
```

Again, I already verified in the ODBC Datasource Administrator (64-bit) that I am using the correct password, I have the correct database, and that I am using the correct driver's name.  Does anyone know what else I may need to include to get a connection to work?

Thank you.

Comment: Check how many characters are in your password, and does this help? https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/sql30082n-security-processing-failed-reason-15-processing-failure-sqlstate08001-linux    You can look in the server's diagnostics file for more details.

Comment: You can get more details in the Db2-server diagnostics. If your Db2-server runs on Linux/Unix/Windows, you can look in the Db2-server db2diag.log (if you have access), or you can query with PDLOGMSGS_LAST24HOURS administrative view (again, if you have access)...   This symptom is usually a __configuration__ issue.

Comment: Local server? Any change there on the server configuration? What type of security is enforced?

Comment: This is a remote DB2 server used by hundreds of employees. I don't believe they have made any security changes since this last worked, or else this would have caused problems for a lot more people than just me.  The reason i'm not asking the security admin team for help is because last time I tried they just kept confusing the situation and made some things worse.  Also, i'm the only person I know using Python.  Everyone else just connects using WinSQL, but that doesn't help me with the program i'm trying to write.

Comment: @Robert , as you have a __configuration__ issue, unless you edit your question to specify your configuration (of Db2-server, and the configuration of the Db2-client) then we cannot help you. You should EDIT your question to specify the platform-and-version of the Db2-server, and what *type* of Db2-client is installed on your workstation( fat client, runtime client, ODBC and CLI client), and *how* it is configured. Once again, give no facts, get no answers. Your choice.